# C++ returning global instance variable instead of it's copy

Tags: c++

I have following problem:
I have this method in class Tree:

```
Node * nearest(const Point & point) const{
    double minDistance = numeric_limits<double>::max();
    Node * nearest = new Node;
    for(Node *n : nodesVector){
        int actualDistance = point.distance(n->point);
        if(minDistance > actualDistance){
            nearest = n;
            minDistance = actualDistance;
        }
    }
    return nearest;
}
```

This method is called from another class as follows:

```
void extend(const Point & rand){
    Node *xNear = this->tree.nearest(rand);
    Node *xRand = tree.add(rand, xNear);
    std::vector<Node *> xNearSet = tree.rNearest(rand, this->RADIUS);
    for(Node *node : xNearSet){
        double c = node->cost + node->point.distance(rand);
        if(c < xRand->cost){
            xRand->parent = node;
        }
    }
    for(Node *node : xNearSet){
        double c = xRand->cost + node->point.distance(rand);
        if(c < node->cost){
            node->parent = xRand;
        }
    }
}
```

I need my method nearest and extend to not change variables in the tree after the extend execution, particularly the nearest node.

So I assumed that using pointer would make this for me, but unfortunately it has not so I have tried to create new pointer to Node, but this approach is not working for me either.

I would like to ask how can I implement it to not change the original node (use only it's copy that won't be treated as local variable or referenced the original one) that is used as nearest?

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

**EDIT:**
Maybe I'll little bit reformulate the question. Now I have removed the memory leak, the line :

```
Node * nearest = new Node;
```

by line:

```
Node * nearest = nullptr;
```

But the main problem was and still is that after the local variable Node *xNear disappears then there are weird values assigned to the original node that was pointed by nearest.

Comment: The code in `nearest` calls `new` and overwrites the variable where this is stored -> MEMORY LEAK.

Comment: If you create class instances with `new()` you should decide which class should hold them, or use [**smart pointers**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) to manage memory de-/allocation for you.

Comment: Previous comments about memory management are spot on. Now, if you want a copy of the object being pointed to, then you're going to have to create one. (By definition, the pointer is pointing to the original object.) For example, if you want to work with a copy of the value returned by `nearest`, you'd need to do something along the lines of `Node copiedNode = *xNear;`

Comment: I don't necessarily need to work with the copy of the nearest or better say I would better like to work with the original instance. I just don't want it to be somehow randomly modified after the extend method. In extend it's just used to add pointers to it for other objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the biggest problem was that there was incorrectly initialized the initial nearest from the constructor (as a local variable without new) so it's values were somehow rewritten to some weird values. It has happened only at the time when there was as a xNear found the initial first from the Node values.

Answer (score 0):

Once you assigned `nearest = n;` the nearest variable no longer points at the `new`ly created object, but to the one found in the `nodesVector` collection – and that one is returned.

if you want to return a copy, then don't overwrite `nearest` with an `n` pointer but rather assign values to the object pointed at:

```
*nearest = *n;
```

(be sure you have proper assignment operator defined in the `Node` class). This way you will return a copy of the nearest object.

Comment: But I don't modify the nearest object any time later, but it seems to me as it is treated as a local variable and thus later somehow randomly reinitialized to some really weird values. 
At the time when local variable xNear disappears the original variable is modified in strange way which I'd like to prevent.

Comment: Well, you are passing the `xNear` pointer, which was found by `tree.nearest(rand)`, to the `tree.add` function – but you don't show the `Tree::add` method implementation, so it's hard to guess if the object actually is not modified. In addition you modify some `parent` links ...are you sure you don't destroy internal consistency of your `tree`? I can't tell, because you didn't show what are parent-to-children and child-to-parent links, you also didn't explain what conditions are kept in the tree (and which may be violated) during the structure's life.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your troubles are related to other operations in your code. How does Tree::add() work in your implementation? How is the tree populated in the first place?

My guess is that nearest is now in two locations in the tree, or a parent pointer is pointing to the same object it originates from.

Look at your tree in a debugger and navigate all the pointers. Additionally print every pointer in the destructor of Node to see whether you are pointing to free memory. Set a breakpoint there to find which scope was exited when the destructor was called.